# Flask set customized test_client endpoint

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I am having trouble testing my Flask application. I am aware of the following snippet

```py
app.testing = True
app.test_client()
```

Though my problem is with the following structure:

```py
@app.route("/a")
def a():
    return "I just got an A!"

@app.route("/b")
def b():
    return "I just got a B!"

@app.route("/c"):
def c():
    return requests.get("localhost:5000/a") + requests.get("localhost:5000/b")
    

app = Flask(__name__)
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

When running `app` from a server, all my tests are passing. But when testing though `app.test_client()` then the function `c()` cannot connect though localhost. And I am getting the following error:
`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /a (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f6b5b7a13d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))`

What is the best practice in such case? Is it to find a way to run the test_client on a specific port and endpoint, or is it to avoid to do localhost requests?

Answer (score -2):

Just replace the local host by your local ip mine is (192.168.2.104). When you run host = 0.0.0.0, it is no longer refered as localhost.

```
@app.route("/c")
def c():
    return requests.get("http://192.168.2.104:5000/a") + requests.get("http://192.168.2.104:5000/b")
```

Also you can't add two requests together...

Comment: The app.test_client() does not run the application. It doesn't matter the value of the host.